# How to obtain the parameters calculated by camera?

Tags: matlab

I need to capture multiple pictures with exactly the same camera parameters (exposure, shutter speed and so on). I want to set camera into Auto mode, obtain the parameters calculated by the camera, set obtained values and set the camera to manual mode so that the values do not change anymore. But this doesn't work, I only get the default parameters (like exposure -7.5850  what is obviously wrong) but not the calculated values, so the image is completely black.

My code:

```matlab
src1 = getselectedsource(vidobj1);

triggerconfig(vidobj1, 'manual');

disp(src1.Exposure);                % Returns default value -7.5850
src1.ExposureMode = 'Auto';
pause(10);                          % Wait some time until camera calculate parameters

calculatedExposure = src1.Exposure;
disp(calculatedExposure);           % I want to get calculated value here (like 1.1), but I get default value -7.5850
src1.ExposureMode = 'Manual';
src1.Exposure = calculatedExposure;
```

When I start camera preview in Image Acquisition Tool I see what are the values calculated for the current scene (e.g. Exposure is 1.1120, Shutter speed is 8.861). The problem is that I can't obtain this values in my code! I only get some value from manual mode (Exposure -7, Shutter 0.04), but not the values calculated by camera

Comment: It was a typo in question code. There is only one camera source in my code.

Comment: Are you sure that `Manual` is a valid parameter for this properties ?

Comment: Try `src1.ExposureMode = 'auto';`, not sure if its is case-sensitive, but in the docs they use lower case. Also I second obchardon's comment

Comment: I also edited your question with the comment you added. It is only "obviously wrong" if you add that information.

Comment: 'Auto' is a valid value: when I don't set camera to manual mode the picture looks correct, but I cant fix calculated values for multiple captures.
'Manual' is also a valid value.

@AnderBiguri, yes, thanks for edit!